# Need Help About php preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string:

```
access":"YOU HAVE 0 BALANCE","machine
```

How can I extract the string in between the double quotes and have only the text (without the double quotes):

```
YOU HAVE 0 BALANCE
```

I have tried

```
if(preg_match("'access":"(.*?)","machine'", $tok2, $matches)){
```

but with no luck :(  .

Comment: No one is going to write your code. What have you tried?

Comment: if(preg_match("'access_token":"(.*?)","machine_id'", $token2, $matches)){

Comment: Put your code in your question by using this [edit] link or the edit link below your question (under preg-match).

Comment: save changed bro

Comment: Your code does not compile. `"'access":"(.*?)","machine'"` is not a valid string literal. You need [`'/access":"(.*?)","machine/'`](https://ideone.com/BEXTPZ)

Comment: i need the output YOU HAVE 0 BALANCE

Comment: Exactly, you have `YOU HAVE 0 BALANCE` with https://ideone.com/BEXTPZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
'/access":"(.*?)","machine/'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IMXjsq/1). The value you need is in Group 1.

**Details**

- `access":"` - a literal substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, since `*?` is a lazy quantifier
- `","machine` - a literal substring

See the [PHP online demo](https://ideone.com/BEXTPZ):

```
$re = '/access":"(.*?)","machine/';
$str = 'access":"YOU HAVE 0 BALANCE","machine';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches[1]);
}
// => YOU HAVE 0 BALANCE
```